# mysql function with group by transform to json

Tags: mysql, group-by

i must Implementation a function like group_concat, but i will transform the array to josn:

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( Time ) AS Gtime FROM A GROUP BY B,C;
```

The result like this :

```
 2016-01-21 15:30,2016-01-21 09:00,2016-01-21 13:00,2016-01-21 19:00,2016-01-21 21:30,2016-01-22 01:30
```

I will transform the text like:

```
  { '2016-01-21':['15:30','09:00','19:00','21:30'],'2016-01-22':['01:30']}
```

so i need how to build the stored procedure

Comment: from what language are you calling mysql? Probably better to do it there

Comment: but some did write a UDF for this kind of things: https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_json#readme

Comment: how can i  use python  map func   and trans  string to dict like this,no use "for"